# function in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

is there any existing function in jquery library with the help of 
which I can submit request and be able to show other page.

like for example in my case I have a page where there are gif's
existing on that and onclick of these gif's I have to show other
page, is there any function available.

Comment: By "show another page," do you mean to say that the page you're currently on will be redirected to that other page?  Or do you mean that a new window will be opened to that location?

Comment: question is not very clear. can you elaborate?

Comment: Images you can click on to go to another page? Sounds like a case for that marvellous invention, <a>...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $("#yourImageID").click ( function () {
       window.location = newlocation;
    });
});
```

> window.location: Returns a  Location
>   object, which contains information
>   about the URL of the document and
>   provides methods for changing that
>   URL. You can also assign to this
>   property to load another URL.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: yes I want the functionality where I have some gif images 
as status indicator on my home screen onclick of which I 
have to show another page (jsp) populated obviously!....
The real problem is that it has some ajax call in it 
for the drop down box population and I have to populate them
so as to view the populate version of it, n all I have to do this 
in jquery so can you people now suggest me what I am suppose to do.